# Wilier Zero9 bottom bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket

Im trying to investigate what type of bottom bracket has by Wilier Zero9 road bike. Looks like some pressfit but Im Not sure,  inner bearing width has 25mm. I have Shimano Ultegra 2x11 6800.[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search [suggests](https://road.cc/content/news/132907-first-ride-wilier-zero-9) it's a BB386Evo. Do you see that number, or maybe just a "386" stamped anywhere on it?

Further confirmation:

https://machiine.com/2017/the-wilier-triestina-zero-9/

https://www.racycles.com/product/detail/5707

That last link makes it sound like it's a custom BB:

"The bottom bracket standard is the Wilier co-designed BB386EVO, designed for 30mm diameter thru-axles and 86mm wide bottom bracket shells"

Comment: I bearly see, thougt it was 686 written but Looks it is 386 as you suggest

Comment: Thanks for the links, great to read such words about my bike

Comment: It appears you need the sort of BB that mates with the BB386EVO frame standard but "adapts" it to 24mm spindles, which is different from just a BB386EVO BB.

Comment: I pine for the days of just a couple of common BB standards.